# How to resize an image array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, image, vision

I'm a newbie with Python, I wonder if there is a way to resize an array which contains an rgb image.

imageA_array[height1][width1][3]

convert to

imageB_array[height2][width2][3]

imageB will result in a smaller image than imageA (height2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use the `scikit-image` library available at http://scikit-image.org/ for python

Then all you would have to do is:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
imageB_array = resize(imageA_array, (height2, width2), anti_aliasing=True)
```